# umbraco - permanent redirect urls

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

I have a website on umbraco CMS and I want to redirect some url's (not many, just about 10-15).
For example: Now i have 2 URL's->

1) xyz.com/home-index.aspx (old)

2) xyz.com/index.aspx (new)

I want to make, that home-index.aspx will redirect to index.aspx, permanently, also for google (now this 2 links works on my site, but googlebot indexed just one of them - "home-index.aspx". I want to have on google search result just "index.aspx", without "home-index.aspx"), and I want, that if user will go on "home-index.aspx", he will be redirected on "index.aspx" (googlebot also). As i said before, now this 2 links in example shows the same content. How can I do this?

Greetings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using [301 Url Tracker](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/301-url-tracker/) package. The package allows you to add entries to the tracker and when a user attempts to access an "old" url, they will be redirected with a 301 (permanent redirect) to the node you selected. Keep in mind that when search engines, such as Google, crawl the page and they get a 301, they will replace the url in their index with the url returned in the 301 response.

Comment: hello again. Simple question - how to use it? I want to redirect all /xyz/***.aspx, where *** represent some pages. Manually? Is it any possibility to redirect all of them from category xyz

Comment: The 301 Url Tracker should create a node for you in the Settings section. You should be able to right-click and create new entries for the tracker. It can take regular expressions so you should be able to set a blanket rule to redirect all with a path that matches a pattern to a specific page.